# Notepad++ doesn't save shortcut changes

Tags: notepad++

Notepad++ ver 6.6.3.

Settings - Shortut Mapper - Save All - change to F5

This works inside the current session, but next time - the default shortcut values are loaded.

How can I save the changes, once done ?

Comment: Try start Notepad++ as admin

Comment: @duDE, how can I do this? I'm using win xp sp3.

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/windows_security_runas.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: @duDE, thanks a lot. Solved. Maybe you should write you comments as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try start Notepad++ as admin: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/windows_security_runas.mspx?mfr=true